# VBA: Type Mismatch with PivotCaches

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a `pivot table` into a document. The following code throws a `mismatch` error, however, I am not sure where/why it is throwing it within the line (the `Set pCache`... line. While the error is thrown, the blank `pivot table` is still created.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    pivot_lastRow = mainSheet.Cells(mainSheet.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'may need to change "A"
    pivot_lastCol = mainSheet.Cells(1, mainSheet.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set pivotRange = mainSheet.Range(mainSheet.Cells(1, 1), mainSheet.Cells(pivot_lastRow, pivot_lastCol))

    Set pCache = wbk.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
             SourceData:=pivotRange).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
             TableName:="Test")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a pivot table and try to fit it into a pivot cache object, that can't work! ;)

Separate the last statement:

```
Dim pCache As PivotCache
Dim pTable As PivotTable

 pivot_lastRow = mainSheet.Cells(mainSheet.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'may need to change "A"
    pivot_lastCol = mainSheet.Cells(1, mainSheet.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set pivotRange = mainSheet.Range(mainSheet.Cells(1, 1), mainSheet.Cells(pivot_lastRow, pivot_lastCol))

    Set pCache = wbk.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
             SourceData:=pivotRange)

    Set pTable = pCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pivotSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
             TableName:="Test")
```

Comment: Although the declaration of `pCache` wasn't shown, this should be the solution. (Declarations `pcache and pTable` would be a good addition though)

Comment: This is it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Rivers31334 : glad I could help! ;)

Comment: @A.s.h : I edited my answer to include the declarations !